# What is missing

Tags: python, selenium

'module' object is not callable

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

python and selenium

```
File "C:/Users/rahusawa/PycharmProjects/LaunchWebDriver/com/LaunchWebDriver/LaunchWebDriver.py", line 2, in <module>

driver=webdriver.chrome(r'C:\Users\rahusawa\PycharmProjects\LaunchWebDriver\chromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: Your code, your question, a title that explains what's the issue...

Comment: I think you need to use a capital "C" in `driver=webdriver.Chrome()`

Comment: You have to give more code in your question, probably an import error or you are calling selenium wrong, but I cant tell for sure because I do not see your code.

Comment: Possibly you need escape slashes before the directory slashes ... "\\"

Answer (score 0):

You're using a wrong className, it's **Chrome** not **chrome**.
Here the Chrome is basically an alias given to the class chrome.webdriver.WebDriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("PATH TO CHROME_DRIVER Executable file")
```